# make space between two Icons in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]I have two icons, how can I make a space between them?

two Icons in App.vue:

```
<v-btn icon class="grey lighten-4">
        <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      
      <v-btn icon class="grey lighten-4">
        <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
```

Comment: please provide the actual look and the expected one

Comment: I edit the post.
please look at it

Answer (score 4):

It's recommended to use built-in class name like `mx-2` to add some margin around the buttons after wrapping them by a div:

```
<div >
     <v-btn icon class="grey lighten-4 mx-2">
        <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      
      <v-btn icon class="grey lighten-4 mx-2">
        <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
</div>
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/pobJpdg)

Answer (score 0):

according to vuetify v-icon api.
we need to use `left` or `right` .
`left`: Applies appropriate margins to the icon inside of a button when placed to the left of another element or text.

`right`: Applies appropriate margins to the icon inside of a button when placed to the right of another element or text